How long can a note on a brass instrument possibly last?
I know that in musical notation, a note can theoretically last forever, but in practice, there are factors that limit this.
From my research, I have identified the following factors that affect how long a note can be sustained:

The player's breath control;

The player's natural lung capacity;

The player's embouchure strength;

The specific technique used (such as circular breathing, where the player breathes in through the nose while simultaneously pushing air out through the mouth);

The instrument’s range;

The pitch of the note being played;

The volume of the note;

The type of instrument (tuba, trombone, horn, etc.);


So, given all these factors and, perhaps, some others that I have missed, which combination of them is most likely to produce the longest note and how long would that be (in seconds)?

Using circular breathing the tone can theoretically last forever. The player only needs to drink, eat, sleep etc., which interrupts the tone.

Not sure if duplicate, but related: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/828/how-can-i-learn-circular-breathing

@VitHenych I suspect that fatigue is a more significant limiting factor than eating or drinking, etc.

@phoog - hmm.  Hard to quantify, though.

I'm curious as to why you want to know this

Way longer than you would want to hear a single note played ;)

@JimM - I was just playing mwith my sound editor and came up with a short peice in very slow tempo using brass a lot. Then I started to wonder if that piece could possibly be playable for real-life musicians. Not knowing much about the brass, I did some reasearch first and then I came here.

A Guinness world record for the longest sustained note on a conch shell is 80 seconds; this was done in one breath and seems the closest Guinness equivalent to a brass instrument. Here's a news story about it; when searching the Guinness site the record appears but has a broken link.
Another record for "Longest sustained note on a didgeridoo" was set at 65.66 seconds. Didgeridoo specifically uses circular breathing normally, but a news story says "Within the didgeridoo community holding a note for up to 30 seconds without using circular breathing is considered a great achievement," so presumably "sustained note" here means without using circular breathing. The didge time is shorter than the conch probably because the larger bore requires more air.
We find a record titled "Longest sustained note on a wind or brass instrument", set at 13.5 minutes... but it was using bagpipes, for which circular breathing is "built-in"; I don't know what factors limited the record-setter to 13.5 minutes.
The bagpipe record referencing "wind... instrument" seems contradicted by other records set on saxophone of over 45 minutes. But the NPR article linked said (in 2017) that "Guinness has cancelled this category," so that might explain the bagpipe's claim. At any rate, even though the saxophone records are single reeds rather than brass, they probably give some indication of the limitations of mouth structures for circular breathing. The article doesn't mention which range of saxophone, but Kenny G. is known for soprano, so once again a small bore probably matters very much.

WOW! Very informative. Thank you!!!

Really interesting, although OP specifically asks about brass. Conch, didgeridoo and particularly bagpipes are cheating! I wouldn't be surprised if the timekeepers had all left at or before 13.5 mins!

Virtually for ever. With circular breathing, air is taken in and a reservoir in the mouth will be available to keep the note going. Reminiscent of a mini bagpipes.  Restrictions are any that would break that cycle - eating, drinking, talking and boredom come to mind.

And fatigue.  People can go for several hours between meals, drinks, etc.; is there anyone whose embouchure can hold the same pitch for several hours?

Isn’t this just a copy of Vit Heynch’s remark? Which does not even really answer the question, because circular breathing is hard, and keeping up for a long time is not that realistic. From a useful answer I would at least expect some insight into actual realistic practice. Surely there are brass guys who can answer things like: “When I practice circular breathing I manage to do it for so long, but I know / have heard about people who can keep it going for even so long”, or something like that.

@Lazy - it's an expansion of the comment - but I thought of circular breathing before reading said comment, and since no-one else had  provided an answer in 4 hrs, felt justified in writing this one - adding what circular breathing is, which Vit's comment did not. While I play brass, I cannot circular breathe, but like you await someone who does. Seems like OP likes it - so far...
